# unicode integral symbol in latex

Tags: unicode-math

I was wondering if there is a way to replace the usual integral symbol with U222B:

http://www.marathon-studios.com/unicode/U222B/Integral

I use xelatex and pdflatex as well.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing specific about unicode here. You have tagged the question unicode-math and if you are using that package you can use U+222b character to access the character or `\int` which will make the same thing.

The visual form of the integral sign, like the visual form of any character, depends on which font is being used, not the input convention.

In particular, the look of the symbol on the web page you reference depends on your local browser configuration, in my case I see

[image]

So the integral from Arial, if you are not on Windows (or even if you are) your browser could be using a different font, and you will see a different shape integral sign.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. My aim is to use this shape of integral in latex. I could not do it anyway.