# How do we get the integral sign below?

Tags: integral

How do we get the integral sign below?
[image]

Comment: $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$

Comment: In what is this different from your previous question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237845/unicode-integral-symbol-in-latex?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

your picture: $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$

arguably nicer: $\displaystyle\int\limits_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What you have a standard integral sign from latex. This integral sign was used in the past and it is in Stewart's book.