# How do I get the "U+222B" Integral sign to use in LaTeX?

Tags: xetex

Below is a sample image of this integral symbol, this is a very common font for the integral symbol, usually seen in textbooks, but surprisingly I couldn't find a way to get this symbol.

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237845/unicode-integral-symbol-in-latex) is the only post I was able to find close to what I need, with only one answer that doesn't help at all.

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_symbol) Page defines the default integral symbol as "Graphical" ,the only thing I know about this symbol is its Unicode Character - U+222B , and that it doesn't belong to a specific font family, it probably only exists in unicode.

[image]

Comment: Are you set on using 222B?  "usually seen in textbooks" makes it sound like you will be content with any integral symbol.  The standard one is $\int$.  Someone else will probably chime in with how to type 222B in XeTeX, and how to redefine $\int$ to use that symbol.

Comment: Hi and welcome! If you use XeTeX and unicode-math, you will get the U+222B integral automatically when doing `\int` in math mode. From the font you selected. Do you want the specific one from the image?

Comment: Take a look at this question: [Which OpenType Math fonts are available?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425098)  Look for the section that discusses "stylistic sets".

Comment: @Teepeemm i only said that for a little reasoning for why I specifically need this font.

Comment: @mickep yes, i was able to find fonts that look closer to this but not exact. 

if possible can you provide the specific code that could compile this unicode character, i’m not familiar with unicode-math

Comment: An alternative approach explored here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170028/integral-sign-int

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I saw that post before, i couldn't find the exact font as the one you can see in the image. this post on the other hand https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88281/how-to-change-font-for-the-integral-symbol/88288 is exactly what i need, but their code no longer seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Every font designer is entitled their preference. Some prefer upright integral signs, other prefer them slanted. There is *no* “standard”.

So the answer much depends on what math font package you use.

If you're using the default Computer Modern fonts, load `cmupint`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nolimits]{cmupint}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \qquad \int\limits_{\Omega} g(x,y)\,dx\,dy
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're using `stix2`, pass the option `upint`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[upint]{stix2}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \qquad \int\limits_{\Omega} g(x,y)\,dx\,dy
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Check the documentation of your math font package for other possibilities.

Comment: There is only `taste` but no `standard`. >_<

Comment: It’s not about fonts, because I’m only looking for a way to insert Unicode character 222B inside math mode, with or without changing the entire font altogether

Comment: @Cristofer You seem to believe that there is a universally established form for U+222B. There's not.

Comment: @egreg If you’re implying that 222B has different fonts, depending on the font i’m using, I could try other math fonts and find the right one, but I’m not sure how can i insert 222B inside math mode (i could insert it using the /text command but it’ll create more work)

Answer (score 0):

the LaTEX \int command why not good for You?

[Integral example](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Integrals%2C_sums_and_limits)

Comment: Nothing wrong with the original I’m just trying to match the fonts from my textbook that’s all really

Comment: Useless answer, really.